# Send CustomData with every WCF Call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an existing WCF service and I use Channelfactory to get the proxy and call the service. Now I have a new requirement to return a custom data for all of my calls. And I dont like the idea of changing the return type to accommodate this new data.

What is the best option I have ? What about sending the data in a custom header?

The function which will use the proxy is in a separate library from where it is created. I prefer this library where proxy is used to have minimal dependency to WCF

Answer (score 0):

You can return a dynamic type or HttpResponseMessage. If you use HttpResponseMessage then you can return the status also.

Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, {response object here});

Comment: we are not using http .

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with custom headers before.  It's nice because it's appended to every single call, automatically, without needing to change anything else.  This was in place of modifying every single call to contain this information.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352678/Add-Custom-Message-Header-in-WCF-4-Calls) is a good tutorial on how to add custom message headers.  (It isn't nearly as complicated as it looks)